# Eliminating latency spikes in TCP connection

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, low-latency

I have a Linux network application that I am trying to optimize for low latency. This application consumes UDP and produces TCP traffic. I have setup a network tap and written some scripts that correlate the UDP traffic with the application's TCP response to compute end to end latency. I have also setup tracing within the application so I can measure internal latency. I have found that typical end to end latency as measured by the capture device is about 20us but on about 5% of the cases the latency can spike to 2000us and even more. Correlating the internal logs with the capture device logs indicates this spike originates in the kernel TCP transmission.

Any suggestions on how I could get a better understanding of what is going on and hopefully fix it? I am running on a 4 HW core machine, with three of the cores dedicated to the application and the remaining one left for the OS.

Update: Further investigation of the PCAP file shows that TCP messages that exhibit high latency are always immediately preceded by an ACK from the system that is the target of the TCP data (i.e. the system to which the machine under test is sending its TCP data). This leads me to believe that the system under test is trying to keep the data in flight under some minimum and that is why it deliberately delays its responses. Have not had been able to tune this behavior out though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's too late for you, but may be it'll help someone in the future. I'm almost sure that you haven't turned off the Naggle algorithm by setting on the TCP_NOWAIT socket option.

Comment: Thanks, but I definitely turned Naggle off.

Comment: Ok then. Another guess: somehow there was something wrong with the TCP window of you connection. When the amount of sent unacknowledged data was equal to the TCP window size, your sender began to stagnate. After you had received an ACK from you peer, the TCP window was freed by the amount of acknowledged data and sender could send some more data again.

You can monitor the current state of TCP window in Wireshark in the TCP subtree of frame dissection.

The reason of problems with TCP window is another topic of discussion